# Replace datasource in test environment for Loopback

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, loopback4

The default acceptance test for PingController created on project startup fails because my application has a Postgresql datasource that is not reachable in test environment. I try to replace this datasource by one in memory but it doesn't work, it still uses the "real" one.

I changed the `setupApplication` method this way :

```
export async function setupApplication(): Promise<AppWithClient> {
  const restConfig = givenHttpServerConfig({
  });

  const app = new MyApplication({
    rest: restConfig,
  });

  const datasource = new juggler.DataSource({
    name: 'myds',
    connector: 'memory',
  });
  app.bind('datasources.myds').to(datasource);

  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  const client = createRestAppClient(app);

  return {app, client};
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`app.boot()` scans the project root for artifacts and will override the bindings.

For unit tests or tests that are limited to only a few components, it's preferred to remove `app.boot()` and then explicitly bind each artifact that's required for that test. This will make it easier to detect unexpected artifact dependencies.

Otherwise, ensure that `app.boot()` is called before any manual bindings:

```js
export async function setupApplication(): Promise<AppWithClient> {
  const restConfig = givenHttpServerConfig({
  });

  const app = new MyApplication({
    rest: restConfig,
  });

  const datasource = new juggler.DataSource({
    name: 'myds',
    connector: 'memory',
  });

  await app.boot();
  
  // Move manual bindings after `app.boot()`
  app.bind('datasources.myds').to(datasource);

  await app.start();

  const client = createRestAppClient(app);

  return {app, client};
}
```

Comment: Moving manual bindings after boot solved my problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad it helped! Be sure to mark the answer as the "correct" answer so that others can better-find the question.